# Save As worksheet from active workbook as new xlxs in new folder removing the linked datasources

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

Excel 2016
Looking for the correct syntax to saveas a workbook with out the linked files.  what is the correct Type:=?????

This is what I have so far

```
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, FileName:=FilePath3, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: *without the linked files* - do you mean you want a *values only* copy of the worksheet? Or just value out the hyperlinked cells and not the formula cells?

Comment: my worksheet is an invoice containing internal links, I want to export it and have it still retain it's format but without the internal links (Data only) with format.

Answer (score 0):

The [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840291.aspx) method can only export to [PDF or XPS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfixedformattype.aspx) format.

To create a values only copy of any worksheet use the below code:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("mySheet") 'change as needed

ws.Copy 

Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
wb.SaveAs "C:\MyFolder\MyWorksheet.xlsx"
```

Comment: how does that save a worksheet as a new workbook?  also How does that save the file without the links?

Comment: @KarenSchaefer - are you asking because it didn't work? or because you want to know how it works? If the 2nd, research the `Copy` method of a worksheet and the line `.Value = .Value` line will flatten any formulas in the file. Then you can save the workbook as you wish (edited that command in there, thought I thought you would know it.)